# How to fill HTML5 input[type=range] on the left side of the thumb with CSS only for chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I already know that there are properties for firefox and ie:

example for Firefox :

```
input[type="range"].slider-track::-moz-range-progress {
      background: red;
}
```

Is there any equivalent for chrome (only css3)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. Only, at the moment, for Firefox & IE.

Comment: thanks for your answer !